# SSL Configuration for WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm working on the SSL Configuration for WSO2 and currently following [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Creating+New+Keystores) article. Now i had a .pfx file which i converted to a .jks file using

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore < pkcs12 file name >.pfx
>   -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore < JKS name >.jks -deststoretype JKS

The next step was to extract a .csr (Certificate Request Signing) from the .jks using

> keytool -certreq -alias certalias -file newcertreq.csr -keystore newkeystore.jks

After having the .csr file extracted, the article asked to provide that .CSR file to the CA. For testing purposes, they preferred [this](https://www.instantssl.com/free-ssl-certificate.html) to have a free SSL Certificate for 90 days.

The site asks for the content of the CSR file and gave me the following error

[image]

> Your Domain Name may not contain a * Please purchase a Wildcard
>   Certificate if you wish to use a * in your Domain Name

Please note that my certificate is for a domain: *.domain.com, **its pretty obvious** that i'll have to purchase a wild card certificate for this but i'm currently trying to set up a TESTING ENVIRONMENT just to be sure before purchasing a particular domain certificate AND for that, i'm looking for alternatives to get the following files:

- The Root certificate of the CA i.e. AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
- Intermediate certificates i.e. COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt, COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
- SSL Certificate signed by CA i.e. test_sampleapp_org.crt

I tried [this](http://getacert.com/signacert.html) and it gave me a **domain.cer** file which is not what i need. Any guesses? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @Bhathiya could you please specify your comment?

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 1):

For development, you can export a self-signed certificate with this `keytool` command.

```
keytool -export -alias certalias -file test_sampleapp_org.crt -keystore newkeystore.jks
```

Comment: thank you for your response however i'm having difficulties in comprehending your answer, what do you mean? What step should i replace this with? i already have the .jks file!

Comment: This will give you the `test_sampleapp_org.crt` file (i.e. public certificate) in your question.

Comment: Edited the answer with the values in the question.